# React - prop is undefined when loading the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing an issue with a React component which I want to use a certain prop in one case and another prop in a different case.  Let me show you what I mean.

```
class GizmoComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {
                this.props.SomeBoolean
                ?
                <WidgetColumn {...this.props} field1={this.props.field2}/>
                :
                <WidgetColumn {...this.props} field1={this.props.field1}/> {/* field1 is already in the props but I'm being explicit */}
            }
        );
    }
}

class WidgetColumn extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {
                this.props.field1.subfield
                ?
                <div>{/* Extensive use of this.props.field1 throughout this component*/}</div>
                : 
                <div></div>
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is that because `WidgetColumn` makes extensive use of the `this.props.field1`, I want to replace the getting of that data with a `field2`.  Everything else remains the same.  Just get the data from a different item in a certain case: `SomeBoolean`.

However, I am getting an error on the `this.props.field1.subfield` saying that `this.props.field1` is undefined so I can't get the `subfield` of something that's undefined. This only occurs when I add the `<WidgetColumn {...this.props} field1={this.props.field2}/>` line to the code.

Why is it undefined since I am defining what it is in the prop?

Comment: Are you sure that the values of this.props.field1 and this.props.field2 in the GizmoComponent are not undefined? It seems to me that everything is passed in correctly to WidgetColumn, it would just be their value that matters for this.

Comment: Without conditionally rendering WidgetColumn you could conditionally set the prop to the component. Just an improvement.

And If you can log the props object and post it here for both "someBoolean" true and false state that will  be help full to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

At first, make sure that `SomeBoolean` and `field1.subfield`/`field2.subfield` properties are passing properly.

My recomendation is: try not to [spread props object](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) `{...this.props}` when passing parameters to the WidgetColumn.

As I understood `GizmoComponent` has `field1` and `field2` props:

```
GizmoComponent.propTypes = {
  field1: PropTypes.object
  field2: PropTypes.object
}
```

So when you will spread `GizmoComponent` props into another component like:

```
// NOTE: there are this.props.field1 and this.props.field2 are available
<WidgetColumn {...this.props} />
```

The result will be the same as you will write:

```
<WidgetColumn field1={this.props.field1} field2={this.props.field2} />
```

It's possible that you have conflict and spread object rewrites the value of the props that you defined manually.
Try to pass field property on next way:

```js
class WidgetColumn extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.field.subfield
            ? <div>The field is subfield</div>
            : <div>The field is NOT subfield</div>
    }
}

class GizmoComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.SomeBoolean
            ? <WidgetColumn field={this.props.field2} />
            : <WidgetColumn field={this.props.field1} />
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        <GizmoComponent field1={{ subfield: true }} field2={{ subfield: false }} SomeBoolean={true} />
        
        <GizmoComponent field1={{ subfield: true }} field2={{ subfield: false }} SomeBoolean={false} />
      </p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare property while Rendering Component.
Like

```
<WidgetColumn props={this.props} field1={this.props.field2}/>
```

If you use this then you can access all **props** of parent component in child component.

That's it.